# Using NUnit v3 alpha how can i get my TestFixtures to run in parallel after noting [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]

Tags: parallel-testing, nunit-3.0

Using NUnit v3 I have added  [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] to 2 separate [TestFixtures].

The positive is they run, the negative is they do not run in parallel, is there a syntax i'm missing that needs to be noted in the code?  I've looked and currently in alpha they support running TestFixtures in parallel not tests within a Fixture.

However I do not see my tests running in parallel.  My target is Sauce Labs.

```
[TestFixture, Description("IE10, Launch url, verify elements, log in, verify landing page")]

//will run test fixtures in parallel

[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

and

```
//second series of tests to run in parallel
[TestFixture, Description("IE9, Launch url, verify elements, log in, verify landing page")]

//will run test fixtures in parallel

[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Each test runs linearly and succeeds, Running at the TestFixture level for my purpose works.  However I feel like i'm missing a concept here.

any help would be great to help me figure out why this wouldn't be working.

thanks
Ren

Comment: I'm not really sure why this got a down vote...I feel as though this is a valid question that actually has yet to be answered on any other forum.  This is no MBUnit, this is NUnit using parallelizable.  My test fixtures are in fact not running in parallel.  From my research you note the above and it should run properly, but it's still running linearly.  Please assist.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are your two TestFixtures doing the same thing? If they are maybe try having only one TestFixture class and having two TestFixture attributes.

```
[TestFixture("chrome", "WIN8")]
[TestFixture("firefox", "WIN8")]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
public class RDTestFixture
{
    public RDTestFixture(string browser, string os)
    {   
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.SetCapability("browserName", browser);
        capability.SetCapability("platform", os);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.168.88.131:4444/wd/hub/"), capability); //address of the GRID hub
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
     }
```

This just ran directly on selenium grid as opposed to Sauce Labs and both ran in parallel.

Comment: Hey Ryan, they are doing the same thing against different browsers.  One is win 9 vs win 10.  Since i'm still new to NUnit I am still learning how to be clever.  I'll give the attributes a go and see what happens.  I'll let you know.  Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: @RenMG Any updates? Have you managed to run multiple tests in parallel?

Comment: Malvin, no I haven't.  I was trying to get it to run in parallel to saucelabs and it just seems to run linearly still.  I'm still working on it, but I have to refocus to getting appropriate output in Jenkins for NUnit 3.0, which due to changes in the xml is now a new issue.  So once i'm done with that i'll circle back around.  I'll update once i find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: @RenMG If you're talking about new TestsResult.xml format and you are using nunit-console to run tests, then you can specify this option `--result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2` and you'll get tests result in old format. That worked for me in TC.

Comment: Malvin! Thanks so much, I just figured that part out! now i'm trying to figure out how to change the name from root to an actual real name...i know in java you just use package name, do you know that portion? thanks again for everything Malvin!

Comment: @RenMG I'm not exactly sure about what name you're talking about. If you were talking about categories name, then you can use include or exclude options. See documentation for more info: http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=3.0

Comment: Malvin, since i'm still under my cool points I can't attach a screenshot, but RANDOMLY my expanded test fixtures worked without using OS and Browser variables.  It's a little clunky but I think it's correlated to the new test runner? Maybe...I added [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
 under each TestFixture.  But it ran my tests in parallel to SauceLabs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I just run selenium tests in parallel using nunit-console.

- Updated tests project to use newest NUnit assembly
- Updated obsolete attributes. You can find complete list [here](http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=breakingChanges&r=3.0).
- Added the following lines to each class, which I want to run in parallel:

  ```
  [TestFixture]
  [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
  ```
- Run NUnit console using this command line:

  ```
  nunit-console.exe C:\Path\My.Tests.dll --include=Selenium --result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2 --workers=4
  ```

Comment: Can you please give more information about how to update assembly and give correct link to list of attributes? Also your console command is not clear for me - you haven't even written NUnit 3.0 console as it is. My named as "nunit3-console.exe". Can you please explain it?